# Can't seem to query specific things using node-mysql with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

```
p_info_query('SELECT * FROM ' + <table> + ' WHERE name = ' + user_name, password, client_connect.id, p_info, function(results) {
```

This seems to produce a Unknown Column 'user_name'.
I searched online for some examples of people doing this, but I couldn't find any.  I want to query for specific things, maybe even comparing 2 values, user and password.

Any help?

// edited for p_info_query function

```
function p_info_query(sql, password, client_socket_id, player_info_object, callback) {
  var result =  mysql_client.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('ERROR IN MYSQL LOGIN CALLBACK : '+ error);
        return false;
    }
    if (results.length  > 0) {

    // do stuff


    callback(true);
    } else {

    callback(false);
    }
    }
});
```

Comment: I am using: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql and user_name is a variable that contains the user_name the client wanted to log into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not quoting the `user_name` so you end up with SQL like this:

```
select * from table where name = whatever
```

where `whatever` is the value of `user_name`, an unquoted value like that is parsed as an identifier (essentially a column name in that context), hence your "unknown column" error.

Presumably `p_info_query` is something of your own as it isn't part of [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql). You should modify it to use placeholders so that it can do things like this internally:

```
client.query(
    'select * from ' + table_name + ' where name = ?',
    [ user_name ],
    function(err, results, fields) { /* ... */ }
);
```

Note the `?` in the SQL and the `[user_name]` array.

---

Now that we know what `p_info_query` looks like, we can fix that too; you should update it look more like this:

```
function p_info_query(sql, params, password, client_socket_id, player_info_object, callback) {
  var result =  mysql_client.query(sql, params, function (error, results, fields) {
    // ...
```

Then you can say this:

```
p_info_query(
  'SELECT * FROM ' + table_name + ' WHERE name = ?',
  [user_name],
  password,
  client_connect.id,
  p_info,
  function(results) { /* ... */ }
);
```

to use a placeholder.

Comment: this results in an "Error: You have  an error in your .... right syntax to use near '?' at line 1.  p_info_query('SELECT * FROM ' + table_name + ' WHERE user = ?',[user_name], password, client_connect.id, p_info, function(results) {  And yes, this is just part of my callback

Comment: What is this `p_info_query` function? Where does it come from?

Comment: @user1328762: I don't think you updated `p_info_query` properly, please see my update.

Comment: omg.  thank you so much!  That works great!  Good thing I asked, cause I would have never figured it out :0